# Embed a video on Facebook from my storage bucket?

Tags: facebook, video, video-embedding

I'm using B2 Cloud Storage to host videos, and Cloudflare as the cdn. I want to be able to share a video on Facebook without having to upload it to Facebook itself. When I post the link in a Facebook post, it just creates a link to the video. Is there anyway to have the video embedded in the post, so you can watch it from Facebook?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Are you sharing the Video URL? A URL to a website that is displaying the video? What is the URL?

Comment: @WizKid I'm trying to share a video URL (https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/sharecdntest/test-video.mp4). It plays from that link, but I can't figure out how to embed it when sharing it (or if it's even possible).

Comment: Try share a link to a website that has og:video pointing to that URL.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that. I was hoping I could just do it from the bucket, but I'm guessing that's not possible? I'll need a website as well? Thanks for your help.